# Can I sum random variables and get a semantically useful result?

Tags: repeated-measures, random-variable, stochastic-processes, measurement

I repeatedly measure two values, $a$ and $b$. Measurement $a$ correlates with two real values $X$ and $Y$. For measurement $b$ the correlation with value $Y$ should be smaller, maybe even 0 while being approximately the same for $X$. I want to estimate value $Y$.

I know for sure that $Y$ has linear influence on both measurements, while I'm not entirely sure how linear the relationship is for $X$ (but it might be).

$X$ and $Y$ follow a normal distribution.
Both measurements are taken with the same sensor.

Can I just subtract measurement $a$ from $b$ and receive a good estimate for $Y$, while knowing that the influence on $X$ is gone?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to re-invent multiple regression, but you need to give us more details.

Comment: I have a sensor that can measure time but is voltage dependent. I can use the same sensor to measure just voltage by using its voltage dependency. I can have two of these sensors run in parallel such that one only measures the voltage depency while the other one measures also time. I want to measure time alone and get rid of the voltage dependency. Can I just take the difference of the single measurements?

Comment: Do you have some data or is this all hypothetical?